# how to create MP4 in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mp4, flv

I have been creating flv videos from my webcam, but due to there on disc size I wish to change them into MP4 which is smaller in size.

Is there a way that I can convert FLV to MP4 in actionscript?

thanks
Saurabh

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852137/how-do-i-encode-video-in-adobe-air-flash

Comment: i m having the FLV video no problems with creating a video. I wish to convert it into MP4.

Comment: As you can see in the link I provided, there are no AS3 libraries for MP4 encoding. Your only options are to use some other software, or to write your own native extension to do that in Adobe Air (ANE).

Comment: Will the use of FLASCC to bridge with ffmpeg and convert flv to mp4. Will this be a good options.??

Comment: Yes, that could work... Maybe another option could be using Haxe, although I have no idea if that would work.

Comment: But why use AS3 in the first place? you could simply use OpenFrameworks (C++) to record an encode your videos.

Comment: AS3 because I am a ActionScript developer, and haven't touched C/C++ for last 4-5 years.. But now I guess I have to get into C/C++ again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can get it by special webcam, which records in HD quality;
2. You can generate it on client with special, unknown for me, lib;
3. You can write video-stream into media-server, which converts into needed format.
4. You can record it on local, and convert it by any external tool, without AS.

Comment: I am not using any media server and also I want this process to be automated and hence cant use a eternal tool. Have to find a work around in action script.

Comment: try translate code by FlasCC of flv2mp4 encoder,
and use it directly by generated lib.
But performance won't the best, relate to solution with external lib(ffmpeg, for example).

Comment: I am using ffmpeg now to get the MP4, but the video and audio aren't synced to each other in the converted MP4. The video is extended in length(secs) and audio finishes a few seconds before the video is finished.

Comment: On result, you have one .mp4 file?

Comment: I passed the bytearray to to a function using FFMPEG and it gives the converted MP4.